# How to write method in ASP.net to get the token from OAuthAPI

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0

Getting Access token from OAuth and passing it in the header for each of the request.

I have api at: https://login.microsoftonline.com/48b0431c-82f6-4ad2-a023-ac96dbf5614e/oauth2/token 
And in Postman can see the access token getting returned. 
I am trying to call this APIM api in my existing 4.5 .NET application. And wrote the following:

```
Dim client = InitializeTokenClient()
    Using content As New StringContent(String.Empty)
        Dim response = client.PostAsync($"48b0431c-82f6-4ad2-a023-ac96dbf5614e/oauth2/token", content).Result
        If (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
            response.
        End If
        Return response
    End Using
```

I am not sure how to access the access_token from the response object and also how would I be passing the access token to make subsequent APIM api calls?

Comment: Can you not just deserialize the json that is returned and take the access_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the access_token from the response by deserializing the response:

Add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` and add `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization` to the top of your file. Then the following code will get the access_token:

```
    Dim j As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(response)
    Dim accessToken = j("access_token")
```

You can then use the token when calling the API by adding an `Authorization` header with the value `Bearer <token>`.